# Javascript returns result before all parameters evaluated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found the following example in [ngResource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
  // GET: /user/123/card
  // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];

  var card = cards[0];
  // each item is an instance of CreditCard
  expect(card instanceof CreditCard).toEqual(true);
  card.name = "J. Smith";
  // non GET methods are mapped onto the instances
  card.$save();
  // POST: /user/123/card/456 {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
  // server returns: {id:456, number:'1234', name: 'J. Smith'};

  // our custom method is mapped as well.
  card.$charge({amount:9.99});
  // POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
});
```

As I can understand, the second parameter of function `query()` is a function, which evaluated on success result of resource query. But simultaneously, this function takes the variable `cards` which is assigned from result of function `query()`.

I can't understand, if this is normal to Javascript, since every async operation executes single thread?

Or special efforts were taken by creators of `AngularJS` in order to have function paramater executed after it's result returned?

How would I write my own function

```
function myfunction(argument, runbefore, runafter) {
   runbefore();
   POSTPONE runafter();
   return Math.sin(argument);
}
```

which would execute 2nd parameter before itself and 3rd parameter -- after itself?

Comment: The `.query()` method in the code you posted only has one argument.

Comment: Yes, and it's one argument is a function, who accesses the result of `query()`. How is this possible?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, but if I understood the question correctly, `.query()` returns an empty object that gets "filled" with the response before the callback is executed.

Comment: In fact, there's a very thorough explanation of what's happening in the documentation you've linked to (under the header "Returns").

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Hard to tell from your question, but I think what you are asking about is how to resolve a bunch of different async calls all at once only after all the results have been returned. Is this correct?

Comment: OP doesn't seem to want to clarify, so voting to close.

Comment: Actually I got clearer understanding according to @Juhana comments, although it is not clear enough yet. Event if returned object is empty, how is it possible to make callback after return?

Comment: ??? A callback is *always* run after returning from the function if the function is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you are asking how it is possible for the callback function to be called after the return statement. One way that this is possible is through builtin functions that call another function at a later time. Take this code for example:

```
function doItLater(arg1, callbackFn) {
    setTimeout(1000, callbackFn);
    return arg1;
}
```

This will return the same argument that it was passed, and the callback function will be called later (about 1 second after the function has already returned). There are other ways a callback function can be delayed. For example, with an `XMLHttpRequest`, a callback function can be called after an HTTP response has been received. You can also connect to user events, so that a function will be called when the user does something specific.

If you want a little clarification on how things like `setTimeout` work in a single-threaded environment, I would suggest reading [this article by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).